# Regex File Content Scanner with Capturing Groups

Tags: windows, gratis, text-search, regex, file-search

I am looking for a UI tool that scans files (filtered by file name patterns, maybe also regular expressions) in a given directory (tree) for occurrences of a given regular expression and displays results of capturing groups for each match in a table.

Basically, I'm looking for a mixture of [grepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) and the regex result tables from online Regex testers like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)** is capable of that:

[image: Notepad++ Search]

- **scans files filtered by file name patterns:** 'Yes, see the "Filters" box in above screenshot.
- **for occurrences of a given regular expression:** Yes, see lower left radio box
- **displays results of capturing groups for each match in a table:** No grouping unfortunately, but results are listed and you can double-click on each to open the corresponding file and directly jump to the hit.
- **gratis:** yes.
- **Windows:** yes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/)?

- It allows you to scan file name and contents.
- It allows regex.
- It displays the results in a table.
  [image]